# Плавные рост div

Tags: html, jquery, css, анимация, jquery-mobile

Необходимо при `vmousedown`,чтобы высота блока увеличивалась,при `vmouseup` останавливался рост. Это реализовано у меня так

```
var intervalTimer1 = 0;
$(document).on("vmousedown", "#btn", function() {
  var rost = 0;
  intervalTimer1 = setInterval(function() {
    rost++;
    console.log("rost =" + rost);
    $('#planka').css("height", rost + "px");
  });

});

$(document).on("vmouseup", "#btn", function() {
  clearInterval(intervalTimer1);
  intervalTimer1 = 0;
});
```

Все работает,но не совсем плавно,иногда дергается.С помощью метода `animate` лучше,но все равно иногда с дерганьем идет как лучше это оптимизировать.

[Тут пример](https://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/hqpe3qnv/2/)

Comment: Можно сделать через css анимацию, и при отпускании что бы `animation-play-state` добавлялась и тогда высота останется текущей, но максимальная высота будет ограничена, устраивает вас такой вариант?

Comment: `var rost = 0;` вынесите из функции, у вас дергается потому что рост всегда начинается с нуля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо @Qwertiy - посмотрел подробнее про `requestAnimationFrame` и состряпал вам примерчик насчет плавной анимации. Через секунду после запуска процесс заканчивается и выводится кол-во добавленных дивов, в секунду как раз и получается 60 кадров/итераций.

```js
$(function() {

  var globalID;

  function repeatOften() {
    $("<div />").appendTo("#divs");
    globalID = requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);
  }

  $("#stop").on("click", function() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(globalID);
  });

  $("#start").on("click", function() {
    globalID = requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften)

    setTimeout(function() {
      cancelAnimationFrame(globalID);
      $('#res').append('<div>stop</div>');
      $('#res').append('<div>' + $('#divs div').length + '</div>');
    }, 1000);


  });
});
```

```css
#divs div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: orange;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<div id="res"></div>

<div id="divs"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Выполнять таймер каждые 4мс весьма неоптимально. К тому же неправильно рассчитывать на частоту вызова этого таймера. Интервал таймера следует изменить, чтобы получить 60 кадров в секунду. А ещё лучше использовать `requestAnimationFrame`.